# Magento SEO - Sub Category url's without parent categories

Tags: magento, url, seo, root, categories

I am using Magento 1.8 and I want sub-categories url's without parent/root category into it or want every url to be on root without putting redirects.

For e.g

Appreal -> Women

1. Tops
2. Bottoms

Appreal -> Men

1. Formals
2. Casuals

Now I want url's to be  :
 **Women**

mysite.com/womens.html instead of mysite.com/appreals/womens.html

**Tops**

mysite.com/tops.html instead of mysite.com/appreals/womens/tops.html

**Formals**

mysite.com/formals.html instead of mysite.com/appreals/mens/formals.html

Is there any setting in default Magento 1.8 to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6):

Open the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url` and comment the below line

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
//    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//}
//elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
//}
```

under function `getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)`

and re-index the Catalog URL Rewrites from Index Management.

You should overwrite `getCategoryRequestPath()` function in your local codePool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in the admin

> Admin -> System -> Config -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Search Engine Optimizations (set to NO)

Comment: And this does what? Only disable the above situation (where subcategories become root url categories) - or is much more disabled?